# SQL Server 2008 query to fill the null values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need a query on below table

TABLE

```
ClienName   Bal0    Bal1    Bal2        Bal3        Bal4        Bal5        Bal6    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A           600     600     NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL    
B           Null    100     NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL    
C           NULL    NULL    200          NULL       NULL        NULL        NULL        
D           NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL        130         130     
E           510     510     NULL        510         510         NULL        NULL    
F           170     170     NULL        170         170         NULL        170 
G           210     210     NULL        210         210         210         210     
H           20      20      NULL        20          NULL        NULL        NULL
```

**Result:  I would like to see the above TABLE as below, which query can do it? please help**

```
ClienName   Bal0    Bal1    Bal2        Bal3        Bal4        Bal5        Bal6    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A           600     600     600         600         600         600         600     
B           100     100     100         100         100         100         100     
C           200     200     200         200         200         200         200     
D           130     130     130         130         130         130         130         
E           510     510     510         510         510         510         510     
F           170     170     170         170         170         170         170 
G           210     210     210         210         210         210         210     
H           20      20      20          20          20          20          20
```

Comment: Looking at this, I *assume* you want "if the row has any values, populate the NULL values with that value". Is that correct? What should happen if a row has NULL values but differing non-NULL values? What if a row is completely NULL? Please describe the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: the rows are more than these, right?

Comment: @Bob, 1>Your assumption is correct.    2>In this case, there is no chances of getting all null values.

Comment: Hang on, are those values *always* the same and you really just want the first non-null column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you want from your very limited example set, just go through the table and fill it column by column.

One pass in the forward direction:

```
UPDATE theTable
SET Bal1 = Bal0
WHERE Bal1 IS NULL AND Bal0 IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE theTable
SET Bal2 = Bal1
WHERE Bal2 IS NULL AND Bal1 IS NOT NULL;

...
```

And one pass in the reverse:

```
UPDATE theTable
SET Bal5 = Bal6
WHERE Bal5 IS NULL AND Bal6 IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE theTable
SET Bal4 = Bal5
WHERE Bal4 IS NULL AND Bal5 IS NOT NULL;

...
```

This also (assuming "Bal" means balance, and the number has something to do with time) handles the case of differing values in columns as time increases.

---

If instead you just want the first non-null column, try the `COALESCE` operator:

```
SELECT ClienName, COALESCE(Bal0, Bal1, Bal2, Bal3, Bal4, Bal5, Bal6) AS firstBal
FROM theTable
```

Comment: that could take forever... :-)

Comment: @codingbiz Yes it could very well take forever, but I'm also assuming it only has to be run once :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only query max (assuming only one value per row) and not update existing table then you can do this

```
declare @table table(clientname varchar(5), bal0 int, 
                    bal1 int, bal2 int, bal3 int, bal4 int, bal5 int, bal6 int)

insert into @table 
select 'A', 600, 600, null, 600, 600, null, null
UNION ALL
select 'B', null, 120, null, null, 120, null, null

;with cte as (
select clientname, (SELECT MAX(val) 
                    FROM (VALUES (bal0),(bal1),(bal2),(bal3),
                          (bal4),(bal5),(bal6)) AS value(val)) As mCOL
from @table 
)

select t.clientname, mCOL as bal0, mCOL as bal1, mCOL as bal2, mCOL as bal3, 
mCOL as bal4, mCOL as bal5, mCOL as bal6
from @table t inner join cte c on t.clientname = c.clientname
```